# Is the term "mobile set" correct?

Tags: meaning, terminology, word-usage

Whenever I try to reach someone and their phone is switched off, it says "دستگاه مشترک مورد نظر خاموش می‌باشید - the mobile set is off".

Searching "mobile set" on the web yields obscure results and I haven't seen any native speakers use it.

Is the term "mobile set" correct in English?

Comment: Google Translate thinks it's Farsi: The desired common *station* is turned off.

Comment: @YosefBaskin It is Farsi indeed, but the translation's a bit off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems like "mobile set" is idiomatic and current in Indian English and perhaps some other dialects:

- [Pickpockets take fancy to politicians' cellphones](https://m.timesofindia.com/city/patna/pickpockets-take-fancy-to-politicians-cellphones/articleshow/5201479.cms) (Patna News - Times of India): "…a minister who also lost his mobile set to a pockpocket".
- [Complaint against mobile dealer dismissed](https://m.timesofindia.com/city/chandigarh/complaint-against-mobile-dealer-dismissed/articleshow/7202900.cms) (Chandigarh News - Times of India): "…stated that he had purchased a Mobile set…"
- [Three held with stolen mobiles worth Rs 1.75 lakh](https://www.thehitavada.com/Encyc/2019/9/4/Three-held-with-stolen-mobiles-worth-Rs-1-75-lakh.html) (The Hitavada, India): "Police succeeded in nabbing three youths involved in mobile set snatching…"
- [Tale of T&T mobile subscribers' woes](https://bdnews24.com/amp/story/bangladesh%2Ftale-of-tt-mobile-subscribers-woes) (bdnews24.com, Bangladesh): "…he uses Grameenphone SIM card in his mobile set as an alternative."
- [The mobile phone as your next-of-kin!](https://guardian.ng/features/youthspeak/the-mobile-phone-as-your-next-of-kin/) (The Guardian Nigeria): "A once-reputed case of a husband was in the bath and in the course of this, his mobile set 'needed his attention'."

It is not (nor was it ever, to the best of my knowledge) used in American or British English (or any of the Englishes that are most closely related to those). See [Cell phone? Cell? Mobile phone? What's the "correct" term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/10094/191178) (As an American, I tend to just call them "phones".)

Answer (score 3):

It is an obsolete usage.

In the early days of radio, it was common to talk of a *radio set*, or *television set* as the device for receiving the communication using radio or television waves.  Over time, the *set* has been dropped.

By extension, you translation is using *mobile set* as the device for receiving mobile communications.  It is not wrong, just a throwback to the 1950s and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

In USA it is usually called a **cell phone**.
In UK it is usually called a **mobile phone**.

We don't say "mobile set", but it can be shortened to just [mobile](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mobile) or [cell (9b)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cell)

> The mobile phone is switched off.
> The mobile is switched off.